# Null pointer exception when attempting to parse string into java.util.date

Tags: java, mysql, spring, date, jdbc

Image of `step into` for `saveEmployee` method:

[image]I am learning Spring+JDBC, and trying to get SQL date-datatype into Java as java.util.Date or java.sql.Date object, and running into null pointer exception.

Code in the main method for inserting data into `Employee`tabke that causes exception:

```
//the following parses date string into java.util.date
    ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
    EmployeeDAO empDao = (EmployeeDAO)ctx.getBean("employeeDao");
    Employee employee = new Employee();
    employee.setName("Robert");
    //the following parses date string into java.util.date
    employee.setJoining_Date((new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy")).parse("12/30/2016"));
    employee.setSalary(200);
    employee.setsSN("837463");
```

Definition of the setters in `Employee.java` model class:

```
import java.sql.Date

public void setJoining_Date(java.util.Date joining_Date) {
        this.joining_Date = new java.sql.Date(joining_Date.getTime());
}
public void setJoining_Date(Date joining_Date){
        this.joining_Date = joining_Date;
}
```

Method:

```
public void saveEmployee(Employee e){
    this.jdbcTemplate.update(this.employee_insert, new Object[]{e.getName(), e.getJoining_Date(), e.getSalary(), e.getsSN()});
    }
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.springdao.EmployeeDaoImpl.saveEmployee(EmployeeDaoImpl.java:49)
    at com.springclient.EmployeeExec.main(EmployeeExec.java:28)
```

Please also advise about best practices regarding implementing such code.

Spring.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
            xmlns:xsi ="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation ="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-   
            2.0.xsd">

    <bean id ="dataSource" class        
      ="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
      <property name ="driverClassName" value ="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name ="url" value ="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/branch_db"/>
      <property name ="username" value ="root"/>
      <property name ="password" value ="root"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id ="jdbcTemplate" class               
      ="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
      <property name ="dataSource" ref ="dataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id ="employeeDao" class  ="com.springdao.EmployeeDaoImpl">
      <property name ="jdbcTemplate" ref ="jdbcTemplate"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: Thank you, please see above edit for exception.

Comment: It says exception in `EmployeeDaoImpl.saveEmployee`. Could you please check your saveEmployee method.

Comment: There is no exception in parsing otherwise, it could have given ParseException.

Comment: `private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate` of the `EmployeeDaoImpl` class is `null`. Is it a best-practice to initialize it in the `main` method as `empDao.setJdbcTemplate((JdbcTemplate) ctx.getBean("jdbcTemplate"));`?